# Mail Permissions on a File Server Resource Manager Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing, exchange-2010

In 2008 server the File resource manager can be set up to alert users when they go over their quota etc. This is all configured however the email notifications are not working.

They have been configured but the event log shows that the user does not have permission to send to the exchange server.

There isnt an option to chosse who to send the email from.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an exchange connector issue. I simply added the address of an appliance in our network that does mail filtering and is set to forward mail.